# conditionally add ng-checked attribute in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I want to add to the following:

```
<input  type="radio" ng-name='{{quest.id}}' ng-model='$parent.$parent.choice.input'  ng-value='{{option}}' id='{{quest.id}}-{{option.id}}' ng-required='required'>
```

An attribute: ng-checked='checklast'

only if some condition is true,how do i do that?

Comment: What is the condition? Why not just put the condition in the `ng-checked` itself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just an example

```
<input type="radio" ng-checked="testModel.child_1 && testModel.child_2" ng-model="isChecked"/>
```

**EDIT**

if you using ng-repeat for displaying the list of radio then

```
<input  type="radio" ng-name='{{quest.id}}' ng-model='$parent.$parent.choice.input'  ng-value='{{option}}' id='{{quest.id}}-{{option.id}}' ng-required='required' ng-checked="$index == $last">
```

Comment: nope, i meant i want something like this: <input  type="radio" ng-name='{{quest.id}}' ng-model='$parent.$parent.choice.input'  ng-value='{{option}}' id='{{quest.id}}-{{option.id}}' ng-required='required' ng-checked='checklast'>